# Почему middleware это плохо?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Почему с помощью фреймворков люди пытаются от них избавиться и выставляют это, как главную положительную сторону? Почему middleware это плохо?

Comment: Относится в частности к nodejs/express.

Comment: Вероятно стоит добавить тег `best-practice`. А так, это очень субъективно всё.

Comment: А кто вам вообще сказал, что Middleware - это плохо? Адепты MVC?